# Stopwatch loops

Tags: objective-c, stopwatch

im making a stopwatching using Xcode 4 as a single view app.. i had a question though. when the milliseconds are counting, they go infinately. i want them to reach 9 and then start back again at 0. i also want the seconds to reach 59 and then go back to 0.
here is my code in my viewcontroller.m file:

```
- (IBAction)start{

    myTicker = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(showActivity) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];  


    myTicker2 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:.1 target:self selector:@selector(showActivity1) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    myTicker3 = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:60 target:self selector:@selector(showActivity2) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];


}
- (IBAction)stop{

    [myTicker invalidate];
    [myTicker2 invalidate];
    [myTicker3 invalidate];
}
- (IBAction)reset{

    time.text = @"00";
    time1.text = @"00";
    time2.text = @"00";
}


- (void)showActivity{

    int currentTime = [time.text intValue];
    int newTime = currentTime + 1;
    time.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", newTime];

    }



- (void)showActivity1{


    int currentTime1 = [time1.text intValue];
    int newTime1 = currentTime1 + 1;
    time1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", newTime1];


}


- (void)showActivity2{


    int currentTime2 = [time2.text intValue];
    int newTime2 = currentTime2 = 1;
    time2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", newTime2];



}
```

and here is my code in the .h file.

```
    IBOutlet UILabel *time;
    IBOutlet UILabel *time1;
    IBOutlet UILabel *time2;

    NSTimer *myTicker;
    NSTimer *myTicker2;
    NSTimer *myTicker3;
}

- (IBAction)start;
- (IBAction)stop;
- (IBAction)reset;


- (void)showActivity;
- (void)showActivity1;
- (void)showActivity2;

@end
```

any answers on how to do this would be greatly appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In your case I would use only 1 timer (one counting milliseconds) and 4 int vars (hours, minutes, seconds and milliseconds). And then on timer tick you just test

```
if (milliseconds > 999)
{
    seconds++;
    milliseconds = 0;
}
if (seconds > 59)
{
    minutes++;
    seconds = 0;
}
if (minutes > 59)
{
    hours++;
    minutes = 0;
}
```

so by doing this you have one timer that manages all your variables. I wrote this code on a fly so it might have a spelling error.